# struct unpack case with 'Bf' formatter

Tags: python

Can someone explain this to me? Why is unpack behaving like this (adding 4 times 0x00 instead of once in first case)?

`Python 3.6.0 (v3.6.0:41df79263a11, Dec 23 2016, 08:06:12) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32`

```
struct.pack('Bf', 0, 1342.34)
b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\xe1\xca\xa7D'

struct.pack('B', 0)
b'\x00'

struct.pack('fB', 1342.34, 0)
b'\xe1\xca\xa7D\x00'

struct.pack('Bf', 4, 1342.34)
b'\x04\x00\x00\x00\xe1\xca\xa7D'

struct.pack('fB', 1342.34, 4)
b'\xe1\xca\xa7D\x04'
```

I can use `>, <` formatters but:

```
struct.pack('<Bf', 0, 1342.34)
b'\x00\xe1\xca\xa7D'

struct.pack('>Bf', 0, 1342.34)
b'\x00D\xa7\xca\xe1'
```

So I do not get the rule

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> By default, C types are represented in the machine’s native format and byte order, and properly aligned by skipping pad bytes if necessary (according to the rules used by the C compiler).

[source](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment)